# in Visual Studio Code, how can i trigger intellisense in an html django template file to get parameters from a .py file under same app?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

I'm learning Django and I would like to know if there's a way to trigger intellisense within an html django template file to get a parameter declared in a python class from another file under the same app, I'm trying to get the question__text declared in a class in the models.py file. this is by the way the tutorial from the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your model.py class as well. BTW you can directly access methods in Html created in Models class.

Comment: Hi! yes i can access it directly, question.question_text would work fine within the details.html template, my issue now is how can I trigger intellisense within the details.html template or any html template within the app for that matter to capture methods declared in other .py files. thanks!